# Can だけど and しかし be used in the same way, or is one considered more formal?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, word-usage

I see だけど used frequently in conversations, whereas しかし is predominantly used on TV programs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

しかし is more formal. It`s often used at the beginning of a sentence, 
しかし is like "however." だけど is like "but."

"However," is definitely more formal than "but." 
Think of Shikashi and Dakedo in the same way :-)

My wife is Japanese, and she told me this.